# Enums as key of a Map with DBref with spring data mongo

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to save and retrieve documents mapped to a class into Mongodb using spring data mongodb with a map field.

Here is a simplified version of my objects in java :
An enum :

```
public enum MyEnum {
   VALUE1, VALUE2
}
```

And an entity to be persisted :

```
public class Entity {

  @DBRef    
  private Map<MyEnum, MySubEntity> mapField;

  public Entity(Map<MyEnum, MySubEntity> mapField){
      this.mapField = mapField;
  }
}
```

I have a simple Repository to save entities and retrieve them. After a save, the document is correctly created in MongoDB.

The problem occur when I try to retrieve it. The object Entity is created and returned by the repository, but any attempt to access or use the `mapField` field will fail with the error : `"java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyEnum"`
When using java debugguer to spy on the retrieved Entity object, the mapField field seems to have String as keys as opposed to MyEnum.

I have tried unsuccesfully to register a custom converter for this type.

My question is : is there anything I can do to match my use case, or is my model just not supported by spring data mongodb and I should alter it?

**Update** :

The problem seems to be related to the use of @DBRef on the map. I have tried without it and the Entity is retrieved correctly. Not sure why this is...

Comment: I only know that one the mongodb side you can use `enum: ["VALUE1", "VALUE2"]` too. And there is `EnumMap` in java.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Keys in MongoDb should be `String` type. You can create converter to convert your keys to String type before adding to database.Using `toString()` method to your key could be a solution.

[Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2981) is a good explanation and probably the answer to your question .

Comment: Thanks, but I have now confirmed that the map can be used with enum and spring mongo data. I can only assume they have they custom implementation on top of the driver.
I have updated my question to reflect this.